# Using foreach to display stars by duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to display a list of national birds from a table that lists a variety of national symbols (flags, flowers, etc.), where field Symbol includes the names of specific symbols (e.g. brown pelican). I would also like to put asterisks or star images next to the most popular national birds. For example, the Andean condor might get a gold star because it represents three or four countries, giving it several rows in the table...

```
IDArea | Symbol
Ecuador | Andean condor
Bolivia | Andean condor
Peru | Andean condor
```

I have a script that's supposed to do that, but it isn't working right, probably because I'm not doing it correctly.

My query works fine when I paste it into phpMyAdmin > SQL...

```sql
SELECT GS.N, GS.IDArea SymArea, GS.URL, GS.PostURL, GS.Unique, GS.Title,
 GS.MyKind2, GS.Symbol, GS.Latin, GS.Desig, GS.DesigGen, GS.DesigGroup, GS.Date, G4.Common,   G4.Latin,
 GG.N, GG.IDArea, GG.Name GName, GG.Type, GG.IDParent, GG.IDParent2, GG.Parent, GG.Parent2,  GG.IDReg
 FROM gs AS GS
 LEFT JOIN gs2_latin AS G4 ON G4.Common = GS.Symbol
 LEFT JOIN gw_geog AS GG ON GG.IDArea = GS.IDArea
 WHERE GS.DesigGen = 'bird' AND GG.Type = 'nat' AND GS.Symbol != ''
 OR GS.DesigGen = 'bird' AND GG.Type = 'dep' AND GS.Symbol != ''
 GROUP BY GS.IDArea ORDER BY GS.N
```

But when I add my "Popular Birds" script, it doesn't display correctly. Depending on how I modify my code, it might display every row twice (or three or four times), or it displays two rows for a bird that represents two nations, but a bronze star appears twice in one of those rows, whether than once in each row.

I think the problem is somewhere in here:

```php
$Symbol = str_replace('_', ' ', $row['Symbol']); 
$Symbol = $Symbol.$RefStar;
$Symbol = str_replace($Symbol, '<tr><td>'.$Symbol.'</td></tr>', $Symbol);
```

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to add the array brackets, changing $Symbol to $Symbol[] or where I should put the brackets. Nothing I try works.

Here's the entire script:

```php
echo '<table>
<thead><tr><th>Country</th><th>Bird</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>';
$data = array();
$symbols = array(); 
while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
$data[] = $row; 
$symbols[] = $row['Symbol']; 

//Get counts for each symbol with symbol name as key 
$counts = array_count_values($symbols); 

foreach($data as $k => $row){ 

$cnt = $counts[$row['Symbol']]; 

if($cnt > 3){ 
    $RefStar = 'Gold'; 
}elseif($cnt == 3){ 
    $RefStar = 'Silver'; 
}elseif($cnt == 2){ 
    $RefStar = 'Bronze'; 
}elseif($cnt < 2){ 
    $RefStar = ""; 
} 

 $Symbol = str_replace('_', ' ', $row['Symbol']); 
$Symbol = $Symbol.$RefStar;
 $Symbol = str_replace($Symbol, '<tr><td>'.$Symbol.'</td></tr>', $Symbol); 
 echo $Symbol;
} // END FOREACH
} // END WHILE LOOP

echo '</tbody>
</table>';
```

**EDIT:**

Based on these database values, four table rows should feature "Andean condor," followed by a gold star, while two rows should display "barn swallow," followed by a bronze star.

```
IDArea | Symbol
Colombia | Andean condor
Ecuador | Andean condor
Bolivia | Andean condor
Peru | Andean condor
Austria | barn swallow
Estonia | barn swallow
```

Note: The field IDArea actually holds country CODES (e.g. bol for Bolivia). My query joins to a table named gw_geog, which provides the actual country names. The table gs2_latin is simply a list of scientific names with all possible common names...

```
Common | Latin
bison | Bison_bison
American bison | Bison_bison
American buffalo | Bison_bison
```

Here's the result of SHOW CREATE TABLE gs...

```sql
CREATE TABLE `gs` (
 `N` mediumint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `IDArea` varchar(7) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `URL` varchar(75) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `PostURL` varchar(44) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `Unique` char(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `Title` varchar(75) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `Subtitle` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `MyKind2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Symbol` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `Latin` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `Desig` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `DesigGen` char(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `DesigGroup` varchar(7) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `Date` char(4) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `Dupe` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `G1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`N`),
 KEY `IDArea` (`IDArea`),
 KEY `URL` (`URL`),
 KEY `Title` (`Title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4896 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

Comment: You seem to think the problem is around symbol.  Is the field null in the database by chance?  Maybe try in your SQL to set null to empty. `AND ISNULL(GS.Symbol,'') != ''`

Comment: If a country doesn't have a national bird, then field Symbol is NULL. When I replace AND GS.Symbol != '' in my query with AND ISNULL(GS.Symbol,'') != '', I get an error message - there's Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL''

Comment: I forgot mysql is a little different on that function.  It would be `AND ISNULL(GS.Symbol) != 0`

Comment: Thanks, but when I add that to my query it returns an empty result set.

Comment: We'll let us take a step back.  If you issue the query in MySQL workbench do you see duplicate results with your original query?  The results could be filtered in the query or the code.  So we need to establish where the problem is.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired output based on it? Better yet create [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: @ drewlander - Wow, that's weird you mentioned MySQL Workbench. I learned about that program and installed it just half an hour ago; I haven't been able to connect to my database with it, though.

@ petern - SQOFiddle is new to me, too; I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Well, I can't connect to a database in MySQL Workbench, and I haven't figured out SQLFiddle yet. However, I edited my original post and pasted the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE at the end. As you can see, that's a pretty complex table; one of my goals is to simplify it. But I think it can just about be stripped down to the field Symbol for this exercise. I pasted the query into phpMyAdmin > SQL, and it works fine. So it looks like the problems are caused by the foreach script I added...either that or I'm display the results incorrectly (or in the wrong place).

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom If you still need help I'd strongly suggest you spend a few minutes and put together relevant sample data (a few representative rows per table) for all involved tables and the desired output and post it in your question. As far as I understand your requirements ranking can be done totally on MySQL side.